# Meaning of square bracket in java stacktrace

Tags: java, dependencies, stack-trace

I encountered below error. I can solve NosuchMethodError by changing some of the dependency in gradle file.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent.safeConstructPutInt(Ljava/lang/Object;JI)V
    at io.netty.util.internal.ReferenceCountUpdater.setInitialValue(ReferenceCountUpdater.java:67) ~[netty-common-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.33.Final]
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractReferenceCountedByteBuf.<init>(AbstractReferenceCountedByteBuf.java:50) ~[netty-buffer-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
    at io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBuf.<init>(PooledByteBuf.java:45) ~[netty-buffer-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
    at io.netty.buffer.PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.<init>(PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.java:47) ~[netty-buffer-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
    at io.netty.buffer.PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.<init>(PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.java:29) ~[netty-buffer-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
    at io.netty.buffer.PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf$1.newObject(PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.java:34) ~[netty-buffer-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
    at io.netty.buffer.PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf$1.newObject(PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.java:31) ~[netty-buffer-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.ObjectPool$RecyclerObjectPool$1.newObject(ObjectPool.java:77) ~[netty-common-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.33.Final]
```

But I wonder what is the meaning of square bracket. It seems like that there are two jar files are included.

```
~[netty-buffer-4.1.33.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
```

In this case which dependency will be used in run time?

Comment: Thanks! Now I understood that tilde means some of uncertainty. In this case which code is executed in real world between multiple dependencies ??